# Retag questions using "drupal" and "views" to "drupal" and "drupal-views"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

[There are 383 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+views) tagged [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) and [views](/questions/tagged/views) (compared to [606 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+drupal-views) tagged [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) and [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views)), where [views](/questions/tagged/views) is wrongly used, as in Drupal "Views" is the name of a module (for which there is already [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views)), and it is not used to refer to a database view (to which [views](/questions/tagged/views) is referring).

Those questions should be retagged to use [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views), which is the correct tag to use. There are 127 followers for [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views), and only 12 for [views](/questions/tagged/views); those 127 followers are users who can answer to Drupal questions, while between the 12 followers there are few users who can answer to Drupal questions (if not none).
I have already changed the excerpt for [views](/questions/tagged/views), which now suggests to use [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views) for questions about the Views module.

This is probably a task for Stack Exchange developers, as only the questions using both [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) and [views](/questions/tagged/views) should be retagged. I have already added [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) to questions that are about the Drupal module; still, manually retagging those questions would require time, if we want to avoid that 383 are suddenly bumped in the front page. I think that I have read on Meta Stack Overflow that, in such cases, it should be asked to do the retagging by altering the database.

Comment: Although the tag wiki says so, the [tag:views] tag doesn't really seem to be restricted to DB views. I see at least as many questions referring to the V in MVC etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there should be at least 3 tags:

- [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views)
- [mvc-views](/questions/tagged/mvc-views)
- [sql-views](/questions/tagged/sql-views)

Or, it might make it easier to select the right tag if they were:

- [views-drupal](/questions/tagged/views-drupal)
- [views-mvc](/questions/tagged/views-mvc)
- [views-sql](/questions/tagged/views-sql)

Comment: The schema I see used is the one used with [tag:drupal-views]. I think it helps who wants to filter out the unwanted tags, who could use, e.g., "drupal-*" as ignored tags.